# How to uninstall .NET SDK previews and older versions when uninstall tool doesn't recognise them

Tags: .net, .net-core, uninstallation

I'd like to uninstall .NET 5 and .NET 6 previews - and just keep the latest .NET 6.

However, the uninstall utility only let me uninstall the version I'd like to keep.

Neither are the old versions present for removal in Settings/Apps & features (Windows 10).

All SDKs have been installed using proper install utility - no zip files - or by Visual
Studio.

I have uninstalled Visual Studio - I use VSCode instead.

List of the current SDKs:

```
C:\>dotnet --list-sdks

5.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.100-preview.7.21379.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

List of uninstallable SDKs (using the uninstall utility):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet-core-uninstall>dotnet-core-uninstall list

.NET Core SDKs:
  6.0.101  x64    [Used by Visual Studio. Specify individually or use --force to remove]

.NET Core Runtimes:

ASP.NET Core Runtimes:

.NET Core Runtime & Hosting Bundles:
```

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet-core-uninstall>dotnet-core-uninstall --version
1.5.255402+e07a3c995ec2d3cf449d37eb50c87e180da12544
```

Any hints on how to get rid of them is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-windows)

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4878 for nitty-gritty details on manually uninstalling dotnet stuff using msiexec. I was able to pretty easily uninstall some vestigial dotnet 5.0.17 packages using "Bulk Crap Uninstaller" freeware which automates most of this for you. https://www.bcuninstaller.com/ In my case I searched for the string "5.0.17" to find the relevant packages. Just be cautious about uninstalling stuff something on your system still needs.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a few months late, but this ended up being quite high up on Google, so just adding the answer here.

You can use the dotnet-core-uninstall tool, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=windows

And can run:
`dotnet-core-uninstall remove --all-previews-but-latest`
If you just want to remove the preview/keep .Net 5, your question was just to keep .Net 6, so you can use `--all-below 6.0.101 --sdk`

You can do a dry run by adding it to the command (dry-run and whatif are synonyms, you can use either):
`dotnet-core-uninstall whatif --all-below 6.0.101 --sdk`

Comment: Did you even read the question? OP already knows about the uninstall tool.

Answer (score 6):

I found a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/2295#issuecomment-423873864) from which I have made a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/m4ss1m0g/3b2b0edd8d5eb73424cbf247265e0bb0) which lists all installed software, including any that is not visible.

#### Examples

Get ALL software containing (case-SENSITIVE) .NET
`Get-Installed -Name .NET`

Get ALL software containing (case-SENSITIVE) .NET AND 3.1.10
`Get-Installed -Name .NET | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName.Contains("3.1.10")}`

Get ALL software containing (case-SENSITIVE) .NET AND 3.1.10 AND Remove that software
`Get-Installed -Name .NET | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName.Contains("3.1.10")} | Select -Expand PsChildName | Remove-Installed`

```
function Get-Installed {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # The name of the software
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $Name
    )
    
    begin {
        $PATHS = @(
            "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
            "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
        )

    }
    
    process {
        $installed = $null
        ForEach ($path in $PATHS) {
            $installed += Get-ChildItem -Path $path |
            ForEach-Object { Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath } |
            Where-Object { $null -ne $_.DisplayName -and $_.DisplayName.Contains($Name) } |
            Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, PSChildName |
            Sort-Object -Property DisplayName
        }
        $installed
    }
    
    end {
        
    }
}

function Remove-Installed {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        $Guid
    )
    
    process {
        Write-Verbose "Removing $Guid"
        $a = "/x " + $Guid
        Start-Process msiexec -Wait -ArgumentList $a
    }
    
}

# Examples
#
# Get ALL software containing (case-SENSITIVE) .NET
# Get-Installed -Name .NET  
# 
# Get ALL software containing (case-SENSITIVE) .NET AND 3.1.10
# Get-Installed -Name .NET | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName.Contains("3.1.10")} 
#
# Get ALL software containing (case-SENSITIVE) .NET AND 3.1.10 AND Remove those software
# Get-Installed -Name .NET | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName.Contains("3.1.10")} | Select -Expand PsChildName | Remove-Installed
#
```